# Как реализовать глобальное событие <F1> в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, события

Задача простая - по нажатию на `F1` показывать файл документации из любого места (виджета) приложения.  Вроде бы [должен сработать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630664/tkinter-global-binding) `w.bind_all()`.  Вот мой код

```
import subprocess

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from pathlib import Path


def help_pdf(tk_event):
    print(tk_event)
    # path_pdf_help = Path() / 'docs' / 'Документ.pdf'
    # ubprocess.Popen([path_pdf_help], shell=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.minsize(1000, 500)

    root.option_add("*Font", 'Verdana 12')
    root.bind_all('<F1>', help_pdf)

    mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="2 5 2 2")
    mainframe.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

    mainmenu = tk.Menu(mainframe)
    mainmenu.option_add("*Font", 'Verdana 12')
    root.config(menu=mainmenu)

    audio_menu = tk.Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
    audio_menu.add_command(label="Выбрать")
    audio_menu.add_command(label="Аудио")

    mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Файл", menu=audio_menu)

    root.mainloop()
```

Однако работает `F1`  только если не наезжать мышкой на пункт меню.   Я ожидал что `F1` будет одинаково срабатывать для любого места, уж коль  `w.bind_all()`  называют привязкой события на уровне [всего приложения](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/binding-levels.html).
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815500/python-tkinter-have-entry-receive-keys-while-menu-is-posted, меню перехватывает все события, если прям надо, собирайте меню в ручную из Toplevel.

Comment: Можно добавить специальное меню "Help" https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/menu.htm#:~:text=to%20system%20restrictions.-,SPECIAL%20MENUS%20IN%20MENUBARS,-Certain%20menus%20in

Comment: https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html#:~:text=Providing%20a%20Help%20Menu описание для мак и для виндоус.

Comment: @СергейКох
Оформитете что то как ответ, если хотите )
Благодарю за помощь

Comment: Ну то есть для винды специального меню нет могу сам воткнуть пункт меню help ?

Идея с F1  нереализуема?

Comment: Я так понял, что если  name='help', то оно будем ставиться самым последним(правым) элементом в строке меню. Я бы оставил F1, они с help не мешают, а дополняют друг друга.

Comment: Вот еще нашел, как можно создать виртуальное событие "F1" в кнопке меню "help" . Добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В связи с тем, что в ОС Windows при активизации виджета menu перехватываются все события, становиться невозможным реализовать постоянно действующий ответ на какое-то определенное событие. В данном случае выход был найден использованием специальной строки menu - help, в которой можно добавить виртуальное событие - нажатие кнопки "F1".

```
import subprocess

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from pathlib import Path


def help_pdf(tk_event=None):
    print(tk_event)
    # path_pdf_help = Path() / 'docs' / 'Документ.pdf'
    # ubprocess.Popen([path_pdf_help], shell=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.minsize(1000, 500)

    root.option_add("*Font", 'Verdana 12')
    root.bind_all('<F1>', help_pdf)

    mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="2 5 2 2")
    mainframe.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

    mainmenu = tk.Menu(mainframe)
    mainmenu.option_add("*Font", 'Verdana 12')
    root.config(menu=mainmenu)

    audio_menu = tk.Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
    audio_menu.add_command(label="Выбрать")
    audio_menu.add_command(label="Аудио")

    mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Файл", menu=audio_menu)

    help_menu = tk.Menu(mainmenu, name='help')
    mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help_menu)
    help_menu.add_command(label="F1 About...", command=lambda: root.event_generate("<F1>"))

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Круто!
Благодарю, то что требовалось )